# error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'TaskInterface[]'

Tags: angular

I'm currently trying to fetch data from my api with Angular 8. The data should have the structure of TaskInterface.

Please see my code and the explanations below:

TaskInterface:

```
export interface TaskInterface {
 id: number;
 name: string;
 description: string;
 due_date: string;
 done: number;
 created_at: string;
 updated_at: string;
 user: object;
}
```

TaskListService:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {TaskInterface} from './task-interface';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TaskListService {

private api = 'http://learning_database.test/api';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

getAll(): Observable<TaskInterface[]> {
  return this.http.get<TaskInterface[]>( `${this.api}/tasks`);
}
}
```

TaskListComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TaskListService} from '../shared/task-list.service';
import {TaskInterface} from '../shared/task-interface';

@Component({
selector: 'app-task-list',
templateUrl: './task-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./task-list.component.css']
})
export class TaskListComponent implements OnInit {

private tasks: TaskInterface[] = [];

constructor(private taskService: TaskListService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.taskService.getAll()
  .subscribe((task) => {
    this.tasks = task;
 });
}
}
```

Response data from Api say here that **this.tasks** is an Object. Therefore the data will not go through ngFor in the template and the page remains white and the console says: 
     **ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed** .
Within the object is an array with the key data. Do I add the key data to task-property in the subscribe method...

```
this.tasks = task.data;
```

...the error message mentioned in subject line shows up,...
    **error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'TaskInterface[]'**
...but the data are properly rendered this way in the template.

I could solve this if I cast the task-property in the subscribe method to type any...

```
this.taskService.getAll()
  .subscribe((task: any) => {
    this.tasks = task;
 });
```

...and everything works fine. But I think that would not be best practice, because of the type of TaskInterface the data should have.

Should I transform the data anyhow via .pipe() and map() in the service? I have unfortunately no idea how to do that.

Thanks for you suggestions...

HTML file for task list component:

```
<div class="ui middle aligned selection divided list">
 <div *ngFor="let task of tasks; let i = index">
  {{ task.id }}
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your clue here is the Error message which tells me your api returns an object with a item in it called data which is an array? You need to use this data array, not the input object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can correct the the types in `getAll` method, like so:

```
getAll(): Observable<{data: TaskInterface[]}> {
  return this.http.get<{data: TaskInterface[]}>( `${this.api}/tasks`);
}
```

Then, subscribing to `getAll`, `task` will have an array of `TaskInterface` in `data` property:

```
this.taskService.getAll()
  .subscribe((task) => {
    this.tasks = task.data; // safe to use, because task is now {data: TaskInterface[]}
  });
```